# Multiprocessing Pool Loses Variable Values on Some Runs

Tags: python, docker, multiprocessing, vscode-debugger

I have code similar to this:

```
import multiprocessing

const = "ABC"
val_list = [1, 2, 3]

args = [{"val": val, "const": const} for val in val_list]
    
with multiprocessing.Pool() as p:
    p.map(functionWrapper, args)
```

When I run with a long `val_list`, e.g., 2,000 entries, then for some of the multiprocessing runs, the `val` variable turns into `"val"` instead of a number, or the `const` variable turns into `"const"` instead of `"ABC"`. Why does this happen and how do I stop it? The extra-strange thing is that the issue with the `val` only happens when I'm running the code in Docker, and the issue with the `const` only happens when I'm running in the VSCode debugger, so it seems like a memory allocation issue with multiprocessing. When I run the `val_list` in sequence without multiprocessing, I get no errors.

Comment: The subprocesses shouldn't be using the `var` or `const` variables - they are passed a `dict` with "var" and "const" keys. Are those passed values the bad strings?

Comment: The first line in `functionWrapper` could be an assertion. Assuming the function is `def functionWrapper(arg):` then add `assert arg["var"] != "var" and arg['const"] != "const", "Bad values passed to subprocess"`.

Comment: What is `functionWrapper` doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You explain that given `args` like

```
[{'val': 1, 'const': 'ABC'},
 {'val': 2, 'const': 'ABC'},
 {'val': 3, 'const': 'ABC'}]
```

occasionally `functionWrapper` will unexpectedly receive
the literal string `'const'`, or `'val'`, as input argument.

Well, that's Bad.

We want to know where those literals came from.
Doing the experiment of changing it to `'konst'`
would presumably show that new string in the buggy output.

Let's think about the pool's actions.
It serialized the `args` list and sent portions of that
to each child for deserialization and processing.
There is something about your production setup that
is more complicated than the nice simple code posted here.
I'm not sure your `val`s are all numeric.
Imagine they are of mixed type, or even that they're all strings.

If the serializer / deserializer does not properly roundtrip
list elements with crazy unicode strings, or other
datatypes, then there is the possibility for it to get
out of sync. We sometimes see such an effect when
roundtripping a dataframe through CSV file format,
where escaping newlines and delimiters isn't completely effective.
Sounds a little far fetched, but it's a working theory.

Also, data values larger than a 4 KiB pipe buffer size
should work fine but might expose unusual sync timing
behavior.

Going even farther out on a limb, perhaps something is racing
and is managing to swallow / discard characters from
the pipe that the child is reading. Verify that your
production code doesn't have any code attempting to
interact in that way. Boil it down to simpler and
and simpler test cases, still more complex than what
you posted, until the symptom no longer manifests.

This is all speculative, but it points to avenues that can
be explored to confirm / reject possible failure modes.

You appear to be using the pool in the correct way -- it *should*
be fine to send such data values down to worker processes.
That is the normal way to use the multiprocessing module.

Performing initialization early or late, before or after
workers are spawned, is one typical gotcha with this module.
You might `open()`, then `fork()`, and the file is open
in both parent and child. Sometimes it is helpful to
lazily defer such actions until after child starts,
so each child has its own private connection to a file.

---

action item:

Rather than serializing the bulk data of interest,
persist that data and just pass row IDs or filenames
down to the children, who use that to retrieve the
bulk data on their own. Doing that experiment will
help you better understand the failure mode and the
per-environment details that trigger it.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much, this comment helped me debug and get it working. I tried type conversions (str to int) and fixing the way the data was being passed to the children, and that got it working somehow.